# React router 4 - Link to page outside react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, passport.js

I'm building a node + react app that uses passport's facebook authentication. Getting this authentication to work involves hitting an express route '/auth/facebook'. Unfortunately as soon as the react app loads up react router 4 doesn't allow links to directly hit the express server and instead searches for a react route matching 'auth/facebook'. In short how do I link to a route within my application but outside of the react app when using react router 4?

Comment: Show your code. It sounds like you're describing an Ajax call, which would not involve react router in any way. Is this a link your user clicks on, or a behind the scenes api call?

Comment: its a simple link in an a tag - <a href = "auth/facebook">Login</a>. But instead of hitting auth/facebook on the express server it looks for a react component.

Comment: `react-router` is for __client__ side routing, you can't get to a server route with relative path. you should include the full domain route to hit a server. (this will cause a refresh).

Comment: @Sag1v I tried that as well. Basically what happened was that initially I had the client running on a separate port (localhost:3000) and the express server running on localhost:8080. But after getting the server to pick up the client side app the server and client were on the same port - because of which I'm not able to hit localhost:8080/auth/facebook anymore.

Comment: Are you using the create-react-app boilerplate? Or Webpack for that matter? Try proxying your api server with `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"` in package.json of your client project.

Answer (score 0):

React Router is only for client side routing. Use fetch API or a similar library for that.

I'll state one way of solving your problem (using fetch and without react router).

1. Remove the href from the `<a>` tag
2. Add an event listener for the click event, `<a onClick={makeCall}>`

Then in the makeCall function, you can call the backend using the fetch API(or axios or whatever),

```
makeCall() {
    fetch('/auth/facebook', options)
        .then((res) => {
            // Something 
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // handle error
        });
}
```